# How to use google maps api to add markers based on certain conditions

Tags: java, javascript, spring, jsp, google-maps

Hey,
     Can someone help me with developing the following requirements?

I have a database that contains parking lot information. For easy interpretation assume that each parking lot has two attributes called id and address.
Through a spring controller I'm passing a list of parking lots to a jsp page(displayAllPL.jsp) that contains the java script for google maps api in this fashion:

```
return new ModelAndView("/displayAllPL").addObject
            ("parkinglots", parkingLotList)
```

So doing something like this I can access each address in the jsp:

```
<c:forEach items="${parkinglots}" var="entry" varStatus="status">
```

${entry.address)

Requirement:
I have to compare each of these parking lot addresses against the user's address(I get this address using geocoder in the google maps api) and find out which of those are within 10 miles distance from the user's address. For all the parking lot addresses within 10 miles range, I need to add markers on the google map. Each of these marker should also contain a link to my controller that will display the parking lot information like shown below:

```
<a href="/<c:url value='/parkingstatus.html?plid=${entry.id }' />"/>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as I totally suck at javascript. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to geocode each of the parking lots and insert the lat/lng into the database (assuming youre using one). Then you use the haversine formula to search your database for parking lots within 10 miles.  If you search this site for haversine youll find plenty of examples.

Comment: Thanks for the help Galen, I'll work on haversine forumala n see how things turn out.